# Stuck on a arithmetic operation error

Tags: ios, swift

I am instantiating an array of UITextField's in the variable labels04. I loop to do some calculations. After the calculations, i attempt to use the index of the array to further calculate my algorithm but get a bad instruction error.

```
    @IBOutlet var labels04: [UITextField]!
    var gpacalc1:Int = 0
    var gpacalcDivide:Int = 0
    var convertIndexGPA:Int = 0
```

On the line

```
gpacalcDivide = gpacalculate / convertIndexGPA
```

i get a THREAD1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(CODE=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode 0x0)

```
    buttonContext
    {
    for label:UITextField in labels04 {


     //calculations ... 

    gpacalculate = gpacalculate + gpacalc!
    convertIndexGPA = labels04.index(of: label)!
    gpacalcDivide = gpacalculate / convertIndexGPA
    gpaTotalCalc.text! = "GPA: \(gpacalcDivide)"
    }
    }
```

I believe it has to do with using labels04.index(of: label)! command. Although it prints as an integer in the console, but when i attempt to use that value for an arithmetic operation I get prompted with the bad instruction error.

Is there a way out of this? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the first iteration of your for loop, `labels04.index(of: label)!` should equal 0 (i.e. the first index), so on the next line -- `gpacalcDivide = gpacalculate / convertIndexGPA` -- you'd be dividing by 0 which would result in an error.